# Find optimal size thorughout trial and errors in presence of errors

Tags: algorithm

This is mostly an algorithmic question, and I am looking for some direction.

I have an endpoint that takes a set of IDs, I can send between 1 and 1000 IDs as batch request.
Time is dominated only by the latency to reach the endpoint.

Hence, the bigger is the batch, the fastest will I complete my requests.

However, if I send more than an unknown `n` IDs, the server will reply with an error.

Moreover, some IDs, if included in any request, will make the server reply with an error indistinguishable from the one mentioned above.

I want to find, in the fastest way possible, both `n` and the IDs that will fail the server.

Comment: How about first finding the "poison pills" using divide and conquer and then find `n`, excluding IDs from the list of poison pills, also using divide and conquer?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Can you please explain how you would go about "using divide and conquer to find the poison pills"? I don't think it's that obvious.